# Trying to set up a chroot environment

Tags: chroot

I do the steps of this guide : http://linoxide.com/ubuntu-how-to/configure-chroot-environment-ubuntu-14-04/

And at

> Now, we're going to need to mount these filesystems within our guest:
>
> ```
> $ sudo mount proc /linoxide/proc -t proc
> $sudo mount sysfs /linoxide/sys -t sysfs
> ```

says:

> mount point /linoxide/proc does not exist

I did the steps above alright but what its missing?

Answer (score 0):

The directory you're using for a mount point has to exist before you can mount something on it. So,

```
sudo mkdir /linoxide/proc
```